# Let $\mathcal{U}$ be $\sigma$ - algebra and show $\mathcal{G}$ is $sigma$-algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

> I'm trying to prove that $ \mathcal{G} $ is $\sigma$ - algebra.
>
> Let $\mathcal{U}$ be $\sigma$ - algebra. Given a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ that do not form a $\sigma$-algebra, we can form $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \text{smallest } \sigma \text{-algebra containing } \mathcal{F}$ where
>
> $\mathcal{F} = \{(a,b):-\infty\leq a\leq b \leq \infty\} $
>
> Thus, $ \mathcal{F} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{F})$. We can also say if $ \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{U}$, then $ \sigma(\mathcal{F}) \subset \mathcal{U}$.
>
> We recall that a function $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{U}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable if $ \{ X \in (a,b)\} \in \mathcal{U} $ for $(a,b)$ any interval, where $\{X \in A\}=X^{-1}(A)=\{\omega \in \Omega:X(\omega) \in A \} $ is the pre-image of a set.
>
> Let $\mathcal{G} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}:\{X \in A \} \in \mathcal{U} \} $. Use the fact that $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra to show that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

$ $

To show that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we need to show that:

(a) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{G}$. How I'm viewing this is that since $\emptyset \in \mathcal{U}$ and that $\emptyset = \emptyset \in A$, then $\emptyset \in \mathcal{G}$.

(b) If $A \in \mathcal{U}$, then $A^c \in \mathcal{U}$, then I need to show that $A^c \in \mathcal{G}$, right? I'm not sure how to go about this.

(c) If $A_{n} \in \mathcal{U}$ then

$$ \bigcup_n A_n \Rightarrow X^{-1}(\bigcup_n A_n) = \bigcup_n X^{-1}(A_n) \in \mathcal{G}. $$
Right?

Comment: For b) use: $X^{-1}(A^{c})=[X^{-1}(A)]^{c}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay. So, I start with $A^{c}$ then take $X^{-1}(A^{c})$ right?